# UML Designer 7.1 on Activity Explorer does not display Diagrams Viewer

Tags: uml-designer

I'm working with UML Designer and as I was following the tutorial from http://www.umldesigner.org/ref-doc/define-the-system.html#Create_A_Project the Diagrams Viewer from the Activity Explorer tab does not appear. (all the viewpoints are selected)

Answer (score 0):

This should work could you report a detailed bug with your configuration in the tracker: https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues
Thanks!